# Homomorphisms of quotient field into domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be an integral domain that is not a field, with quotient field $\operatorname{Quot} R$. We view both as $R$-modules. I want to show that there is no non-trivial $R$-module homomorphism $\phi: \operatorname{Quot} R \to R$.

I thought about this: let $r\in \operatorname{Quot} R$ be such that $\phi(r) = a \ne 0$. Let $0\ne p\in R$. Then
$$ a = \varphi\left(p \cdot \frac{r}{p}\right) = p \varphi\left(\frac{r}{p}\right), $$
so $a$ is divisible by all non-zero elements in $R$.
Now somehow, if $R$ is a UFD with infinitely many prime elements (for example), then we are done, as this would imply $a=0$. But how to do this in general?

Comment: You'll need to use the fact that $R$ is not a field.  Can you use that to find an element of $R$ that $a$ cannot be divisible by?

Comment: Ohhh, that took me way too long. It cannot be divisible by $ab$, where $b \ne 0$ is not invertible, as this would mean that $bc =1$ for some $c \in R$ -- contradiction. Thanks!